# Highcharts - How to set custom colors for the series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to render some charts for a project. My problem is that when I try to set `colors` array in `plotOptions.column`, it doesn't work. Although, it works fine for `plotOptions.pie`.

What I need to do is to set different color presets for different series types. So when I add series of same type, they have colors picked up from their `colors` array. But now, for some weird reason, the default colors are showing although I have defined my own `colors` array for each series type.

Here is the fiddle to better understand what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/c5nhd/1/

And here is the link to official documentation:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Xgsbr/)** of different color for different series of the column chart from our customized array of colors thus overriding the default colors of the highcharts.

code:

```
var colors = ['#FF530D', '#E82C0C', '#FF0000', '#E80C7A', '#E80C7A'];
$( '#container' ).highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
        pie: { //working here
            colors: colors
        }
    },
    colors:colors,
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [25, 34, 15, 17, 19],  
    },{
        type: 'column',
        data: [25, 34, 15, 17, 19],  
    },{
        type: 'column',
        data: [25, 34, 15, 17, 19],  
    }, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: [25, 34, 15, 17, 19],
        center: ['75%', '30%']
    }]
});
```

Comment: Wondering if that's the only way to do it since that's not what I want. This will set the color on series level but I need to set colors on series type level. The thing you have done here could also be achieved by setting `colorByPoint` to `true` in the `plotOptions.column`. Although `plotOptions.column.colors` is listed in the official documentation, don't know why it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean to say by ` I need to set colors on series type level` ? How you want the colors to appear ? Do you want this : http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/RQBLc/    ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that when I add two or more series for type `column`, each series should have its own color picked from the `colors` array.

Comment: I have updated my question and the fiddle to better clarify what I mean.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can refer the fiddle now. I have added multiple series to the column chart !

Comment: Yeah that's a good solution but that doesn't still answer my question. I need `plotOptions.column.colors` to get to work.

Comment: Well, the plotOptions.column.colors` documenation says `A series specific or series type specific color set to apply instead of the global colors when colorByPoint is true.` So to make it work you will have to set `colorByPoint` to `true`

Comment: And after all my answer does satisfies your question as **What I need to do is to set different color presets for different series types.** As this is what you need finally. Am I correct ? Please consider accepting the answer if you find it helpful as it will help other users like you find a correct solution to the problem.

Comment: So `colorByPoint` is the catch here. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to set the **series** **color** and not global options colors or point colors.

Global options colors is an applied set for all charts on the page. It will be ok if you apply it to another chart.

Also, **colorByPoint** will need to be **false**. This is default false, so you can exclude.

Also make sure to set **color** and not **color(s)** if you wish to include a legend. The legend will not know what color to use if you set multiple colors and will just default.

```
$( '#container' ).highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
        column: { 
         //colorByPoint: false,
         //stacking: 'percent',
         },
         pie: { 
            colors: ['#FF530D', '#E82C0C', '#FF0000', '#E80C7A', '#E80C7A']
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        color: '#FF530D',
        data: [25, 34, 15, 17, 19]
    }, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: [25, 34, 15, 17, 19],
        center: ['75%', '30%']
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        color: '#333333',
        data: [15, 27, 10, 23, 21]
    }]
});
```

Here is an update to your js fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/c5nhd/4/

This also works if you wish to stack by percent.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, You should use the latest highcharts.js (Highcharts JS v6.1.4 (2018-09-25)).
I have fixed this using version 6x.